# Asset tokenization on Corda

Tags: corda

Is there an example for issuing and transferring tokens (fungible assets) on Corda?

Can someone please sketch at high-level how this would work?

I am especially interested in the following aspects:

- How does Corda prove that a party owns the tokens (representing cash or securities)?
- Can we keep transactions private? Especially:

  - Only sender and receiver know that transaction took place and with which amount.
  - Receiver doesn't see the total balance of the sender.
  - Sender doesn't see the total balance of the receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By tokens I assume you are referring to fungible assets (one token is the same as another token). In corda this is modeled using contracts - the contract defines the token/assets behavior. For an example of this you can see cash here https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/finance/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/finance/contracts/asset/Cash.kt.

To prove a party owns the tokens corda uses notaries. Each state (an instance of a token - defined in the tokens contract) is checked for validity by the notary, which is done by simply running your contract verification code. You can simply have an ownedBy field for each token state as is done with cash, and require in the contract verification code that the party that put in the cash state owns this cash.

In terns of keeping transactions private, I recommend you take a look at using the swap identities flow. essentially for each transaction a new public/private key pair is generated only known by the parties involved - see https://docs.corda.net/api-identity.html#confidential-identities.

Hopefully this answers your questions/sets you on the right path

Comment: Does the receiver of cash also has to sign the transaction? What about non-validating notary (->privacy): how is it ensured that the non-validating notary doesn’t mark a cash state as consumed which isn‘t owned by the transaction creator/signer?

Comment: The question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870232/how-does-a-non-validating-notary-knows-if-a-participant-is-allowed-to-consume-a/49873290