# How does a non-validating notary knows if a participant is allowed to consume a state?

Tags: corda

Since non-validating notaries in Corda are not performing input/output state validation of a transaction, how does a notary service know that a transaction initiator is allowed to consume specific input states?

For instance, in this simple cash example:

```
State0{} -issueCashTX-> State1{owner:issuer, amount: 1000}
                        -transferTX-> State2{owner:issuer,   amount: 500}
                                      State3{owner:CompanyA, amount: 500}
```

Smart Contract Rules validate that `transfer` transactions are only valid, if input state is owner by the transaction initiator and sum of output amounts is equal to sum of input amounts.

**[Q]**: How the non-validating notary knows that consuming `State1` is ok, since it has no idea about the validation rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He doesn't knows that State1 is ok but He knows if the inputs have already been used in another transactions. Transactions send to the notary have been signed by all peers so the transactions must be valid or that's means that all peers in the transactions are cheating with each other.

Comment: But if someone third would be able to "steal" State1 from the vault of the issuer, he could create a TX using the State1 as input and let sign this by the notary. Since notaray only knows State1 hasn't been consumed yet, he would sign this? However, later in the process, the issuer wouldn't be able to consume State1 a second time, since notary service has marked this as consumed?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to MohamedLEGH's answer some additional information from the discussion at GitHub (https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/2971):

The fraudlent participant could create an arbitrary transaction and let it get signed by the non-validating notary, however, the notary will store the identity of the transaction creator. Since all identities are known, sanctions can be enforced. Moreover there is a mechanism in planing to raise a disupte and revert such transactions. (See https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/transactions/NonValidatingNotaryFlow.kt#L18)